# How to use only the fastest relays?

Tags: configuration

I have heard that in Tor it is possible to increase the speed by using only the fastest relays. However, I did not find anything like this in the [instructions](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en). How can i do this?

Comment: If everyone does it, they won't be the fastest relays any more.

Comment: I find it somewhat unfair that with the 100Mbit speeds my ISP gives me, I only get slow relays. And almost always about 3Mbit to upload and download. Although the torus could be faster (about 40Mbit by count). With the current speeds, even watching video is a torment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "fastest" is a very relative to the clearnet topology: so, for example, one guard can be a blazing fast for you but a laggy hole for another user. The network is reorganizing dynamically, so the manual guard selection is totally not a task to be worried about